# Postfix Whitelist for RBL

Tags: postfix-mta

Googles outgoing Servers are today listen on SORBS

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ot0-f180.google.com[74.125.82.180]: 451 4.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [74.125.82.180] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?74.125.82.180;
```

now I want to whitelist them. But this is not working:

```
whitelist_recipient:
/^mail-.*\.google\.com$/    OK
```

Postfix config:

```
main.cf:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    ....
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/whitelist_recipient,
    ....
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
    ....
```

But why? postmap whitelist_recipient I had do.

And a

```
postmap -q "mail-ot0-f180.google.com" regexp:whitelist_recipient
```

Says: OK

What do I wrong?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of time, I found my mistake!

```
main.cf:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    ....
    check_client_access regexp:/etc/postfix/whitelist_recipient,
    ....
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
    ....
```

It not **hash:** it must **regexp:**